# Why Xcode's default code generated is wrong?

Tags: c++, xcode

When I create a C++ project using Xcode, I will get the code generated by Xcode like this:

```cpp
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
...
}
```

However, the code even could not pass the compile when I use `getopt(argc, argv, nullptr)`, which is defined in `<unistd.h>`.

The reason of the problem is parameter is invalid, so why Xcode does not generate the code like `char * const argv[]`, which could at least pass the compiling stage.

[Xcode's build failed information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F0Jt.jpg)

Comment: I think they're just playing it safe.  You're not _really_ supposed to modify `argv`, although `getopt` does so.

Comment: Just `strdup` each of the `argv` into another array, so `getopt` can modify them.

Comment: @PaulSanders _"You're not really supposed to modify argv"_ According to whom?

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks, I know this might becaue the safety, but why not generate the code like `char *const argv[]`, which could also make sure the code's safety? And I think `char *const argv[]` could make sure the coder could not modify the true parameter whose type is `const char *`.

Comment: @modnar `char* const` and `const char*` are two different things; the former protects you from essentially nothing.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Put it this way: it's a little-visited corner of the C / C++ standard.

Comment: @PaulSanders Can you provide a citation?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I can't, no, but I imagine most people use `getopt` without giving much thought to how it works.

Comment: @PaulSanders Put it this way: the C++ standard says nothing about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're right; this was a bad decision on Apple's part.

Though directly modifying `argv`'s elements is usually frowned upon, it's not inherently "wrong" and indeed some functions like `getopt` expect to be able to. Adding `const`ness there in the default code template not only breaks this, but also goes against [the standard's guidelines](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2.sentence-4):

> An implementation shall allow both
>
> - a function of `()` returning `int` and
> - a function of `(` `int`, pointer to pointer to `char` `)` returning `int`
>   as the type of `main` ([dcl.fct]).

(Though note that this passage isn't claiming that those are the *only* valid types for `main`.)

Personally I'd prefer Xcode did not do this. Perhaps suggesting an improvement via [Radar](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) would be helpful.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your answer. I am agree with you. Maybe I should not use `wrong` to describe the problem. As you say, I think Apple should pay more attention to the details like this question, thanks!

Comment: @Modnar Yeah, seems to me they're just trying to be too clever for their own good.

Comment: @PaulSanders My thoughts exactly!